# Define a Function to get image from label and file name from entry and save as PNG with defined file path in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to save the qrcode generated and displayed on `Label:ShowQr` as png file using a function which includes getting file name from filename entry and iImage data from `Label:ShowQr` and then saving it to a specified path with the name user gives in the filename entry. The function saveQr() is linked to button "Save as PNG".

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox, filedialog
import os.path
import pyqrcode

root = Tk()
greeting = Label(text="Welcome to HASH-QRCoder")
greeting.pack()

ShowQR = Label(root)
ShowQR.place(x=200, y=200)
ShowQR.pack()

def getcode_QR():
    if len(entry.get("1.0", tkinter.END)) != 0:
        global qrcocode, qrcode_xbm
        qrcode = pyqrcode.create(entry.get("1.0", tkinter.END))
        qrcode_xbm = BitmapImage(data=qrcode.xbm(scale=8))
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Please Enter some DATA")
    try:
        showQR()
    except:
        pass


def showQR():
    ShowQR.config(image=qrcode_xbm)

def saveQR():
#want to save the Qrcode (displayed on Label:ShowQr) as png file to specified path when someone clicks "save as PNG" button.
# also want to get the name of file from Filename_entry and add it as filename on that path.        
        


entry = Text(root, width=30, height=10)
entry.pack()
button_qr = Button(root, text="GET QR CODE", padx=10, pady=5, command=lambda:[getcode_QR(),showQR()])
button_qr.pack()
Filename = StringVar()
Filename_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=Filename)
Filename_entry.pack(padx=105,pady=10)
button_save = Button(root, text="Save as PNG", padx=10, pady=5,command=saveQR)
button_save.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what is the problem. Do you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I checked documentation for [pyqrcode](https://pythonhosted.org/PyQRCode/moddoc.html) and it has function `qrcode.png(filename)` to save it. Did you try to use it? And did you tried to get `Filename_entry.get()` ? it seems you could do it few hours or days ago but you waste time for asking for help.

Comment: if you use `place()` then you don't need `pack()`. `place`, `pack`, `grid` are different layout managers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `qrcode.png(outfile)` to save the qrcode as PNG image, but you need to install `pypng` module.

```py
def saveQR():
    filename = Filename.get().strip()
    if filename:
        qrcode.png(filename, scale=8)
```

Note that there is typo in the following line inside `getcode_QR()`:

```
global qrcocode, qrcode_xbm  # qrcocode should be qrcode
```

Also you have called `showQR()` inside `getcode_QR()`, the `command` option for `button_qr` can be changed from:

```
command=lambda:[getcode_QR(),showQR()]
```

to:

```
command=getcode_QR
```

Actually prefer to merge `showQR()` into `getcode_QR()`:

```
def getcode_QR():
    global qrcode, qrcode_xbm
    txt = entry.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    if len(txt) != 0:
        qrcode = pyqrcode.create(txt)
        qrcode_xbm = BitmapImage(data=qrcode.xbm(scale=8))
        ShowQR.config(image=qrcode_xbm)
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Please Enter some DATA")
```

---

Update: use `filedialog.asksaveasfilename()` to get output filename when saving to PNG:

```
def saveQR():
    filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
    if filename:
        qrcode.png(filename, scale=8)
```

Comment: Using qrcode.png to save file the button do nothing.. while using qrcode_xbm.png the save png button gives error on pressing:qrcode_xbm.png(filename, scale=8)
AttributeError: 'BitmapImage' object has no attribute 'png'

Comment: Also i want the save PNG Button to open a file dialog get file name from Filename Entry and Save the file as PNG. to a selected path in file dialog.

Comment: @Saif Did you install `pypng` module? `qrcode.png(...)` works for me if `pypng` is installed.

Comment: yes pyng is intalled and imported as well.

Comment: @Saif Then I don't know why it does not work for you.

Comment: dir = os.getcwd() + "\\Documents"
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.makedirs(dir)
    File_name = Filename.get().strip()
    try:
        if len(File_name) != 0:
            files = [('All Files', '*.*'),
                     ('PNG', '*.png')
                     ]
            file = asksaveasfile(mode="w",filetypes=files, defaultextension=files)
            if file:
                qrcode.png(file, scale=8)
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Please enter a File Name")
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo("Generate the QR code first!")

Comment: with above code the file is saved but it is 0Kb, it means the image data is not written to the file while being saved as png. when i try mode=w inside filedialog it still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to use `mode="wb"` in `asksaveasfile()`.